# Android: error with icons

Tags: java, android

I just added an item (with an icon) on my toolbar.

problem 1 - when i long press the icon a grey box under it appears

problem 2 - the icon is rendered in black while the theme is set to dark.

Comment: You need to add the relevant code. Cannot help without that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem, this is normal. By default, Android displays the `name` of the menu when you long press it (accessibility feature). 
As you should not remove this behavior, you should add a `android:name` to your menu via XML.

For the second problem, the `Toolbar` is not tinting automatically the icons you use in your menus. Only the overflow and the navigation icon are tinted by the toolbar. If you are using a Dark theme, you have to use white icon.

Comment: This means that i will reimport all the icons, this time setting them white. Thank you.

Comment: What if i use vercorial icons... Is there a way to paint them? EDIT: Solved by changing the icon theme to Holo_Dark.

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem i can suggest to use a code like this with bg transparent

```
<ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```

Comment: ok thanks for the suggest. I set as bg color a lighter grey, and... it is better looking now.